# Filtering out multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Supposing a data set with several rows and columns with some columns being 0 (I mean all values in the column are 0's). How one can filter out those columns? I have tried with the following code but no avail.

```
training_data <- Filer(function(x) { !(all(x[, 1:99]==0))}, training_data)
```

UPDATE:

Sorry. In the data set, NOT all columns are numeric, so I need to specify a range from 1:99 for columns.

UPDATE V2: 
Added a part of my data set (using `dput`)

```
structure(list(label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), f1 = c(15, 24, 10, 9, 6, 9), f2 = c(6, 
14, 5, 4, 2, 4), f3 = c(6, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2), f4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), f5 = c(9, 15, 6, 5, 3, 5), f6 = c(3, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2), f7 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f8 = c(4, 11, 5, 4, 2, 4), f9 = c(5, 3, 0, 0, 
0, 0), f10 = c(1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0), f11 = c(1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2), 
    f12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f13 = c(13, 15, 7, 6, 3, 6), f14 = c(0, 
    7, 1, 1, 1, 1), f15 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f16 = c(20, 30, 
    11, 10, 6, 10), f17 = c(5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f18 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), ft19 = c(28, 344, 399, 28, 82, 42), f20 = c(2.15, 
    15.64, 49.88, 4, 20.5, 6), f21 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f22 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f23 = c(6, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2), f24 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), f25 = c(19, 334, 395, 23, 79, 37), f26 = c(0, 
    26, 37, 6, 16, 7), f27 = c(11, 64, 101, 5, 17, 12), f28 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f29 = c(2, 37, 101, 7, 26, 8), f30 = c(0, 
    18, 32, 2, 16, 4), f31 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f32 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f33 = c(3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), f34 = c(5, 44, 
    32, 4, 15, 5), f35 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f36 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), f37 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f38 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), f39 = c(6, 8, 10, 3, 2, 3), f40 = c(4, 6, 16, 4, 4, 
    3), f41 = c(18, 36, 37, 7, 5, 7), f42 = c(0, 18, 27, 0, 14, 
    1), f43 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f44 = c(54, 743, 910, 65, 
    184, 100), f45 = c(14, 133, 91, 25, 18, 40), f46 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), f47 = c(4, 25, 17, 6, 6, 8), f48 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), f49 = c(0.46, 1, 1.5, 1.14, 1.5, 1.14), f50 = c(2.67, 
    1.86, 1.83, 1.88, 1.67, 1.88), f51 = c(3, 9, 1, 2, 1, 2), 
    f52 = c(0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), f53 = c(10, 12, 5, 4, 2, 4), f54 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ft55 = c(3, 10, 3, 3, 2, 3), f56 = c(0.54, 
    0.07, 0.03, 0.32, 0.07, 0.21), f57 = c(0.21, 0.04, 0.01, 
    0.14, 0.02, 0.1), f58 = c(0.21, 0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.05
    ), f59 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f60 = c(0.32, 0.04, 0.02, 0.18, 
    0.04, 0.12), f61 = c(0.11, 0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.05), 
    f62 = c(0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f63 = c(0.14, 0.03, 0.01, 0.14, 
    0.02, 0.1), f64 = c(0.18, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0), f65 = c(0.04, 
    0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0), f66 = c(0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 
    0.05), f67 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f68 = c(0.46, 0.04, 0.02, 
    0.21, 0.04, 0.14), f69 = c(0, 0.02, 0, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02), 
    f70 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f71 = c(0.71, 0.09, 0.03, 0.36, 
    0.07, 0.24), f72 = c(0.18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f73 = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), f74 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), f75 = c(0.08, 0.05, 
    0.12, 0.14, 0.25, 0.14), f76 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f77 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f78 = c(0.21, 0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.05
    ), f79 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f80 = c(0.68, 0.97, 0.99, 0.82, 
    0.96, 0.88), f81 = c(0, 0.08, 0.09, 0.21, 0.2, 0.17), f82 = c(0.39, 
    0.19, 0.25, 0.18, 0.21, 0.29), f83 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    f84 = c(0.07, 0.11, 0.25, 0.25, 0.32, 0.19), f85 = c(0, 0.05, 
    0.08, 0.07, 0.2, 0.1), f86 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f87 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f88 = c(0.11, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0), f89 = c(0.18, 
    0.13, 0.08, 0.14, 0.18, 0.12), f90 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    f91 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f92 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f93 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f94 = c(0.21, 0.02, 0.03, 0.11, 0.02, 0.07
    ), f95 = c(0.14, 0.02, 0.04, 0.14, 0.05, 0.07), f96 = c(0.64, 
    0.1, 0.09, 0.25, 0.06, 0.17), f97 = c(0, 0.05, 0.07, 0, 0.17, 
    0.02), f98 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f99 = c(1.93, 2.16, 2.28, 
    2.32, 2.24, 2.38), f100 = c(0.5, 0.39, 0.23, 0.89, 0.22, 
    0.95), f101 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f102 = c(0.14, 0.07, 0.04, 
    0.21, 0.07, 0.19), f103 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f104 = c(0.02, 
    0, 0, 0.04, 0.02, 0.03), f105 = c(0.1, 0.01, 0, 0.07, 0.02, 
    0.04), f106 = c(0.11, 0.03, 0, 0.07, 0.01, 0.05), f107 = c(0, 
    0, 0.01, 0.04, 0.01, 0.02), f108 = c(0.36, 0.03, 0.01, 0.14, 
    0.02, 0.1), f109 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f110 = c(0.11, 0.03, 
    0.01, 0.11, 0.02, 0.07)), .Names = c("label", "f1", "f2", 
"f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9", "f10", "f11", "f12", 
"f13", "f14", "f15", "f16", "f17", "f18", "ft19", "f20", "f21", 
"f22", "f23", "f24", "f25", "f26", "f27", "f28", "f29", "f30", 
"f31", "f32", "f33", "f34", "f35", "f36", "f37", "f38", "f39", 
"f40", "f41", "f42", "f43", "f44", "f45", "f46", "f47", "f48", 
"f49", "f50", "f51", "f52", "f53", "f54", "ft55", "f56", "f57", 
"f58", "f59", "f60", "f61", "f62", "f63", "f64", "f65", "f66", 
"f67", "f68", "f69", "f70", "f71", "f72", "f73", "f74", "f75", 
"f76", "f77", "f78", "f79", "f80", "f81", "f82", "f83", "f84", 
"f85", "f86", "f87", "f88", "f89", "f90", "f91", "f92", "f93", 
"f94", "f95", "f96", "f97", "f98", "f99", "f100", "f101", "f102", 
"f103", "f104", "f105", "f106", "f107", "f108", "f109", "f110"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to paste the output here. What is this that you've pasted?

Comment: @Arun. Its a csv format my data set.

Comment: for the data you've posted: `label` is the only non-numeric column. So you could do: `df[-1][!colSums(df[-1] == 0) == nrow(df[-1])]` (check my answer).

Comment: @Arun. All are numeric except "label" column having value "A" or "B". But I have excluded some other non-numeric columns for the sake of simplicity. But still the goal is same to trim out columns where all values are 0 like f12.

Comment: yes, I understand that. And I've offered you a solution. I **really** don't know what is wrong with your problem anymore. What exactly are these answers lacking (or the one I've provided in mine and above in this comment)?

Comment: @Arun. I am testing your solution.

Comment: @Shahzad: You said your numeric columns are `1:99`, but in the data you `dput` the first column is a factor. In general you shouldn't use indices for this, since those can change, but test for `is.numeric` instead. Check my solution for an example.

Comment: @adibender. Please have a look at the comment in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the solutions using `all(x == 0)` it is slightly more efficient to use `any(x!=0)`, because `any` stops after the first instance of an element being `!=0`, which will be important with growing number of rows.

To provide a different solution using `plyr` and `colwise` (`dat` being the `dput`data):

```
library(plyr)
f0 <- function(x) any(x!=0) & is.numeric(x)
colwise(identity, f0)(dat)
```

The idea is to go through every column in dat and return it (`identity`), but only if `f0` returns `TRUE`, i.e. the column has at least one entry `!=0` and the column `is.numeric`

**EDIT**: 
To do this for every data.frame in your list, eg. `training_data <- list(dat, dat, dat, dat)`

```
training_data_clean <- lapply(training_data, function(z) colwise(identity, f0)(z))

sapply(training_data, dim)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    6    6    6
[2,]  111  111  111  111

sapply(training_data_clean, dim)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    6    6    6
[2,]   74   74   74   74
```

**EDIT2**:
To retain the label column:

```
lapply(training_data, function(z) cbind(label = z$label, colwise(identity, f0)(z)))
```

Comment: Could you please provide a more thorough solution. I am not good at R. How to fit the above solution in 

trainingdata <- lapply(trainingdata, function(data) { } ).

I have several data sets like these in the list trainingdata. Thanks.

Comment: The solution seems to work fine but how can I retain the first column i.e. "label" in trainingdata.

Comment: Great. Is it possible that somehow we can modify the code to put the condition that exclude those columns too which are all 1's (I mean all the values of the column are 1).

Comment: @Shahzad: this is straight forward by manipulation of `f0`, if you can't figure it out yourself, you should read a R tutorial. I think your original question has been answered sufficiently. You can ask a new question refering to this one, if new questions arise...

Comment: Thanks. I will post an other question.

Comment: @Shahzad: Ok, you should really figure out how to apply the solution to all elements `!=1` instead of `!=0` by yourself though ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
training_data[, !colSums(training_data == 0)]
```

**Based on question update:** (filter applied to columns 1 - 99)

```
idx <- which(as.logical(colSums(training_data[, 1:99] == 0))) # find columns
training_data[, setdiff(seq_along(test_data), idx)]           # exclude columns
```

Comment: I remember a comment from @hadley in a post as a reply to JDLong's answer about suggesting not to use `-which(.)`. I don't recall why.. and I am trying to get hold of that post.

Comment: @Arun I remember also , but here I am not even sure that solution is right, I test it on my data and I get an odd result. the Op don't give a reproducible example, so the question is confusing.

Comment: @Arun compare these to see possible danger of negative subscripts:  `c(2,3)[-which(1>c(2,3))]` compared to `c(2,3)[!(1>c(2,3))]`. Both try to extract values which are greater than one.

Comment: @Arun I think you refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame

Comment: @Hemmo, (+1) right on target. I'll have to write this down somewhere for another time!

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the comment. I wasn't aware of the problem of `numeric(0)`. I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colSums`

```
dat <- diag(10)
dat[1,1]  <- 0
dat[5,5]  <- 0

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1

colSums(dat) == 0
 TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So to remove the columns with 0 , you just do this

```
dat[  ,colSums(dat)!=0]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

**EDIT**

This assume that all data have the same sign, to avoid this ,

```
dat[  ,colSums(abs(dat[,1:99]))!=0]
```

Comment: This only works if there is no negative values in the data, otherwise it can happen that the column sum is zero even though not all values in the column are zero.

Comment: I am sorry. I have to get back my words. The solution is still not working.

Comment: @Shahzad you don't tell why and how? can you add a reproducible example to your question and the expected result.

Comment: @agstudy I have posted some part of my data. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @agstudy: I think it doesn't work, because you build the logical index on `dat[, 1:99]`, but subset on `dat[, ...]`, not `dat[, 1:99][, ...]`

Answer (score 2):

```
training_data[,apply(training_data, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) !all(x == 0))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way using `lapply` as it is a `data.frame`. `apply` internally converts `data.frame` to a `matrix` I believe.

```
df[!unlist(lapply(df, function(x) all(x==0)))]
```

Or in your case:

```
df[, 1:99][!unlist(lapply(df[, 1:99], function(x) all(x==0)))]
```

**Edit:** Another way using `colSums`. The trick is to use it after checking for `0`.

```
df[!colSums(df == 0) == nrow(df)]
```

If you know which columns are numeric (say, 1:99), then replace `df` with:

```
df[,1:99][!colSums(df[,1:99] == 0) == nrow(df)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(df, 2, Filter, f = function(x){!all(x==0)})
```

I had the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804539/undefined-columns-selected-when-trying-to-remove-nas-from-dfs-in-list).

Comment: I think this is incomplete, because it returns a list with element numeric(0) when `all(x == 0)` instead of a data.frame containing only columns !all(x ==0)