# Filtering out columns in R

Tags: r

Referring to another post# [Filtering out multiple columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223257/filtering-out-multiple-columns-in-r) ; there it was asked to filter out columns with all 0's (All the values in the column are 0). Using the following code:

```
f0 <- function(x) any(x!=0) & is.numeric(x)
trainingdata <- lapply(trainingdata, function(data) cbind(label=data$label, 
                                colwise(identity, f0)(data)))
```

one can filter out columns containing 0's only. There is also a need to filter out columns containing 1's only (I mean all the values in the column are 1). I tried the following:

```
f0 <- function(x) all(x==1) | any(x!=0) & is.numeric(x)
```

OR

```
f0 <- function(x) all(x!=1) | any(x!=0) & is.numeric(x)
```

but its not working.

Comment: Your second function with a logical `AND` rather than `OR` and the check `any(x!=1)` should work.  However, I would write these as two separate functions and do each check independently for clarity.

Comment: @Justin. Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second function with a logical`AND` rather than `OR` and the check `any(x!=1)` should work.

However, I would write these as two separate functions and do each check independently for clarity.