# Select/remove columns under conditions in dplyr (filter columns) R

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

Is there a way to filter out columns based on some condition using `dplyr`? This is a bit confusing because it is the opposite of normal filtering.

I can't find anything directly applicable on SO. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223257/filtering-out-multiple-columns-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame) but they don't do quite the same thing.

Basically, instead of filtering out rows based on a column's value, I want to remove columns based on a row's value.

Here's an example using the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(aa = c("1", "a", "10.2", "12.1", "8.7"), 
                 ab = c("1", "b", "5.3", "8.1", "9.2"), 
                 ac = c("0", "a", "1.8", "21.5", "16.0"), 
                 ad = c("0", "b", "11.1", "15.9", "23.6"))
```

I know it's a strange data set and that the columns have data of varying types. This is actually the reason for the question. I'm trying to clean this up.

Here is a `base` solution, using traditional subsetting, to this, which returns columns "ab" and "ad":

```
df[, df[2,] == "b"]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using `dplyr`? I tried using `filter`, `select` and `subset` to no avail, but I might be using them incorrectly in this case.

Comment: @GeorgeWood Checked the link. Does not address using a condition. I can select manually. I'm trying to have R do it for me.

Comment: what's wrong with the baseR solution??

Comment: I would suggest to try to find a better title for the question, in order to make it better visible for search engines. Such as: Select columns containing string within rows. "Filter" is kind of reserved for filtering rows. Ideally, try to avoid using 'df' and similar, as those are baseR functions and you're messing up with other people's environments.

Comment: @Tjebo I changed the title to reflect your concerns. However, I kept a reference to "filter." Although this question may not be about filtering, I think that the concept is similar and, therefore, people may search for this solution using that term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `select_if` which is a scoped variant of `select`:

```
df %>%
  select_if(function(x) any(x == "b"))

#    ab   ad
# 1   1    0
# 2   b    b
# 3 5.3 11.1
# 4 8.1 15.9
# 5 9.2 23.6
```

Here, I supplied a function to find any column containing "b".

Edit based on your comment below:

```
df %>%
  mutate(row_n = 1:n()) %>%
  select_if(function(x) any(x == "b" & .$row_n == 2))
```

Here, we mutate a variable `n_row` indicating the row number, then add the row number as a condition in the call to `select_if`.

Comment: This is on the right track, but I need it to look at row two because there are other rows in my data set that will contain the same value.

Comment: Edited the answer to add a further condition for the row number.

Comment: Nice solution. Works nicely. I made a slight adjustment that, I think, makes it simpler and more straightforward. I replaced the `row_n` with `rownames` to avoid having to `mutate`. `df %>% select_if(function(x) any(x == "b" & rownames(df) == 2))`. Of course, then we have to call `df` again, so it's a matter of preference. One could also `mutate` out the new column with `mutate(row_n = NULL)` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following method:

```
 df <- df %>%
    select(ab, ad)
```

The good part about using this is that you can also do not select using the following idea:

```
 df <- df %>%
    select(-ab)
```

This will select all the columns but not "ab". 
Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn't answer the question in that there is no condition applied.

Comment: You can use some more stuff inside the select. For example: 

`select(contains("a"))`

For more info have a look here: 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-complete-catalog-of-argument-variations-of-select-in-dplyr/